# How do I make DIVs get assigned an ID chosen from an array in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got my code almost working (Its a slider that can create more divs if the user increases the slider value, or deletes them if they move back down), the issue I am struggling with is that I need to ID each new div as it is made, choosing the names from an array, I feel this should be easy but I cant get it working and I can't find it here.

```
    $('#pos1').on('slide', function (ev) {
      var positions = ["Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliett"];
      var positionValue = $('#pos1').val();
      var gridCount = $('.carousel-inner div').length;
      var objToClone = $('.table-slide');

      if (gridCount < positionValue) {
        for (var i = gridCount; i < positionValue; i++)  $(objToClone).clone().removeClass('active').appendTo('.carousel-inner');

      } else {

        for (var i = gridCount; i > positionValue; i--)

          if ( $('.carousel-inner div:last').hasClass('active') ){
            $('.carousel-inner div:last').prev().addClass('active');


$( "div:last-child", ".carousel-inner" ).remove();
      } else {
        $( "div:last-child", ".carousel-inner" ).remove();
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to set the ID, but if you want to use your positions array, in order, you can use .shift()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I get your intention right, but try

```
for (var i = gridCount; i < positionValue; i++) {
    $(objToClone).clone().removeClass('active').prop("id", positions[i]).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
}
```

This, however, requires the array to be the same length as `( positionValue - gridCount )`.

Also, note that `$('.table-slide')` [selects all elements of the class "table-slide"](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), not just one.